# Is there a place I could get my proofs critiqued?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, self-learning

I'm in the process of teaching myself various topics in math, but I realize that one of the things I'm missing by not taking courses are critiques of proofs on homework. My background is computer science and I've often looked at the code-review stackexchange for critiques of code/coding style. Is there any equivalent for math and proofs?

Comment: This question should probably be in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Posting proofs for others to check is part of what people do here on a daily basis.

Try to boil each question down to something readable in a short enough amount of time though, otherwise you won't get as much attention.